# How to send email with mysql query whose time has been reached

Tags: mysql, php

I am making a php script in which I am fetching the email addresses whose sending date and time has reached.
In my database am having a table emails, which is having the following columns.

```
1.communication_id 
2.name  
3.status    
4.email     
5.senddate
```

This is my query to fetch emails.

```
"SELECT email FROM `emails` WHERE senddate <= NOW() AND status = 'pending'
```

this query is right? if not what needs to be changed?

Answer (score 0):

The query itself looks OK, but there are two things you still need

## NEED #1 : Additional Index

Here is the index you need to add

```
ALTER TABLE emails ADD INDEX status_senddate_ndx (status,senddate);
```

This will cause all pending emails to be grouped together and then ordered chronologically. This will help do an index range scan for datetimes that are marked pending.

## NEED #2 : ID to the Emails

You should collect the communication_id for all those pending emails

```
SELECT communication_id,email FROM `emails` WHERE senddate <= NOW() AND status = 'pending';
```

You will need to refer back to those same IDs in order to delete the emails from the table or change the status from 'pending' to 'sent' after you send the emails.

Answer (score 0):

Technically your approach would work as a minimum requirement. It begs the question what the returned 'email' value encompasses. Is it the ID of an email in a separate email_values table (which would contain body, subject, recipient, etc.) or simply the recipient's email address with the subject and body of an email being default values?

Also for your approach you would have to update status from 'pending' to something else - and what about senddate? Either you update it too and thus lose information on when the request was inserted or you don't and lose information on when the script sent your email.

A better solution would be to put status and status_date into a separate table (along with a foreign key for communication_id or email - IF the later is unique to inner join it on your emails table). That would allow you to insert new communication steps via insert instead of updating and thus would prevent information loss.

Comment: I require "simply the recipient's email address"

Comment: Well, then you don't need an emails table. :)